# Swift progress view completion actions

Tags: swift

Helllo , I am using swift. I have this code that control a progressview on my main view controller. I feed the progress view with a double var containing seconds.  Once the progressview has completed i d like to perfom some actions on the main viewcontroller. but i have no idea on where and how to implement actions.  here is my code :

```
class CounterProgressView: UIView {

    let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.birkyboy.TodayExtensionSharingDefaults")

    private let progressLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    private var progressLabel: UILabel

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        progressLabel = UILabel()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        createProgressLayer()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        progressLabel = UILabel()
        super.init(frame: frame)
        createProgressLayer()
    }

    private func createProgressLayer() {
        let startAngle = CGFloat(M_PI_2)
        let endAngle = CGFloat(M_PI * 2 + M_PI_2)
        let centerPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(frame)/2 , CGRectGetHeight(frame)/2)

        var gradientMaskLayer = gradientMask()
        progressLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter:centerPoint, radius: CGRectGetWidth(frame)/2 - 30.0, startAngle:startAngle, endAngle:endAngle, clockwise: true).CGPath
        progressLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        progressLayer.lineWidth = 25.0
        progressLayer.strokeStart = 0.0
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0

        gradientMaskLayer.mask = progressLayer
        layer.addSublayer(gradientMaskLayer)
    }

    private func gradientMask() -> CAGradientLayer {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds

        gradientLayer.locations = [1.0, 1.0]

        let colorTop: AnyObject = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1).CGColor
        let colorBottom: AnyObject = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0).CGColor
        let arrayOfColors: [AnyObject] = [colorTop, colorBottom]
        gradientLayer.colors = arrayOfColors

        return gradientLayer
    }


    func hideProgressView() {
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
        progressLayer.removeAllAnimations()

    }

    func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Double) -> (Double, Double, Double) {
        let (hr,  minf) = modf (seconds / 3600)
        let (min, secf) = modf (60 * minf)
        return (hr, min, 60 * secf)
    }

    func  animateProgressView() {

        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0

        var temps = sharedDefaults!.objectForKey("roueCounter") as? Double

        println(temps)
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = CGFloat(0.0)
        animation.toValue = CGFloat(1)
        animation.duration = temps!
        animation.delegate = self
        animation.removedOnCompletion = false
        animation.additive = true
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

        progressLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "strokeEnd")
    }

    override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {

    }
}
```

And this the functions on the main viewController that call the progressview :

```
func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Int) {

    sharedDefaults!.setObject(seconds, forKey: "roueCounter")
    sharedDefaults!.synchronize()

    let (h, m, s) = (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)

    if m < 10 {
        counterInfosLabel.text = "FROM CURRENT TIME IN"
        counter.text = "\(h)H0\(m)"
        println ("\(h) Hours, 0\(m) Minutes")
        counterProgressView.animateProgressView()
    } else {
        counterInfosLabel.text = "FROM CURRENT TIME IN"
        counter.text = "\(h)H\(m)"
        println ("\(h) Hours, \(m) Minutes")
        counterProgressView.animateProgressView()
    }

    if h == 0 && (m <= 5 && m > 0){
        counter.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        counterInfosLabel.text = "FROM CURRENT TIME IN"
        PKNotification.toastBackgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        PKNotification.toast("You are Illegal in 5 minutes")
        counterProgressView.animateProgressView()

        var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)
        localNotification.alertBody = "You Are Illegal In 5 Minutes."
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        localNotification.soundName = "chime.mp3"
        localNotification.category = "CATAGORY_1"
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
    }
    if h <= 0 && m <= 0 {
        counterInfosLabel.text = "ILLEGAL SINCE"
        counter.text = "\(-h)H\(-m)MN"
        PKNotification.toastBackgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        PKNotification.toast("You are Illegal")

        var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)
        localNotification.alertBody = "You Are Illegal !"
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        localNotification.soundName = "chime.mp3"
        localNotification.category = "CATAGORY_1"
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide me.

Comment: So how do you know when progress is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the progress view knows what to do when the animation is complete, you could give your `CounterProgressView` a completion handler property:

```
var completionHandler: (() -> ())?
```

Then modify the `animateProgressView` accept and save the completion handler provided by the caller:

```
func animateProgressView(completionHandler: (() -> ())?) {   
    self.completionHandler = completionHandler

    // set up and start animation
}
```

You could then have the animation completion delegate method call this closure:

```
override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {
    completionHandler?()
    completionHandler = nil
}
```

Obviously, now when you start the animation, you can specify what you want to happen when the animation is complete:

```
counterProgressView.animateProgressView() {
    // what to do when animation is done
}
```

Comment: that makes sense , that would have to be implement in the progress view controller class ?

Comment: Everything (except that last step where you're calling `animateProgressView` with a closure) is in your `CounterProgressView` class. Only that last step, where your view controller initiated the animation, happens in the view controller.

Comment: i did this :if m < 10 {
            counterInfosLabel.text = "FROM CURRENT TIME IN"
            counter.text = "\(h)H0\(m)"
            println ("\(h) Hours, 0\(m) Minutes")
            counterProgressView.animateProgressView()
            counterProgressView.animateProgressView() {
                PKNotification.toastBackgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                PKNotification.toast("You are Illegal")
            }
        }     but xcode gives me this error : Connot Invoke 'animateProgressView' with an argument list of type'(() -> _)'

Comment: And what happened? I am not familiar with this `PKNotification` class, nor the rest of your logic, so I don't have anything meaningful to contribute here. But I might suggest a more minalistic test: `print("starting animation ... "); counterProgressView.animateProgressView() { print("You are illegal") }` and see if (a) you reached this bit of code at all (because you start animation in a couple of places); and (b) that the "You are illegal" message shows up when the animation is done. Isolate the basic animation completion logic from the details of what you do inside that closure.

Comment: And did you change the `animateProgressView` method declaration and implementation like I said, adding a `completionHandler` parameter (and changing the method to save the completion handler)?

Comment: i answered my own question to show the changes of the progressview swift file

Answer (score 0):

Yes i think i did follow exactly :

```
import UIKit

class CounterProgressView: UIView {


let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.birkyboy.TodayExtensionSharingDefaults")

var completionHandler: (() -> ())?

private let progressLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

private var progressLabel: UILabel

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    progressLabel = UILabel()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    createProgressLayer()


}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    progressLabel = UILabel()
    super.init(frame: frame)
    createProgressLayer()

}



private func createProgressLayer() {
    let startAngle = CGFloat(M_PI_2)
    let endAngle = CGFloat(M_PI * 2 + M_PI_2)
    let centerPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(frame)/2 , CGRectGetHeight(frame)/2)

    var gradientMaskLayer = gradientMask()
    progressLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter:centerPoint, radius: CGRectGetWidth(frame)/2 - 30.0, startAngle:startAngle, endAngle:endAngle, clockwise: true).CGPath
    progressLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    progressLayer.lineWidth = 25.0
    progressLayer.strokeStart = 0.0
    progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0

   gradientMaskLayer.mask = progressLayer
    layer.addSublayer(gradientMaskLayer)
}


private func gradientMask() -> CAGradientLayer {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds

    gradientLayer.locations = [1.0, 1.0]

    let colorTop: AnyObject = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1).CGColor
    let colorBottom: AnyObject = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0).CGColor
    let arrayOfColors: [AnyObject] = [colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.colors = arrayOfColors

    return gradientLayer
}


func hideProgressView() {
    progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
    progressLayer.removeAllAnimations()

}

func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Double) -> (Double, Double, Double) {
    let (hr,  minf) = modf (seconds / 3600)
    let (min, secf) = modf (60 * minf)
    return (hr, min, 60 * secf)
}

func animateProgressView(completionHandler: (() -> ())?) {
    self.completionHandler = completionHandler

    progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0

    var temps = sharedDefaults!.objectForKey("roueCounter") as? Double

    println(temps)
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = CGFloat(0.0)
    animation.toValue = CGFloat(1)
    animation.duration = temps!
    animation.delegate = self
    animation.removedOnCompletion = false
    animation.additive = true
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

    progressLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "strokeEnd")


}



override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {
    completionHandler?()
    completionHandler = nil
}
```

}

Comment: And yet you say that when you have `print("starting animation ... "); counterProgressView.animateProgressView() { print("You are illegal") }` that you get an error message that says "Cannot Invoke 'animateProgressView' with an argument list of type'(() -> _)"?!? OK, first "clean" your project (from "Product" menu choose "Clean"). Second rebuild. If you're still getting that error, make sure you don't have another class lingering about with a `animateProgressView` method without a parameter. It's going to be something simple like that, methinks.

Comment: I had 2 of the same Progressview class for 2 different progressview. i Simplified it and left only on of them and it works like a charm . thanks for the help and patience